# Module Exports best practices for ECMA6 class

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, ecmascript-6

In my nodejs project extensively using the ECMA 6 classes, my question is with regards to exporting this classes.
There are 2 ways for instance:

```
class MyClass{
    constructor(myAttr){this._DB =DB;}
    someMethod(){DB.save()}
}
module.exports=Myclass;
```

Second way:

```
class MyClass{
    constructor(){}
    someMethod(obj){var DB =require('DB'); DB.save(obj)}
}
module.exports=new Myclass();
```

First one relies on the .js to instantiate the class and pass on the variables(DB) While object creation of MyClass, there would however be as many objects created as many requests are coming in of MyClass. However the Class level attributes of MyClass(Db in this case) would not be duplicated.

Second Approach instantiates MyClass but the variable DB is created as many times as the call to SomeMethod is made.

Third approach not so neat is to create global variable for DB and use it :

```
'use strict'
const DB = require('DB')    
class MyClass{
    constructor(){}
    someMethod(obj){DB.save(obj)}
}
module.exports=new Myclass();
```

I would like to know what approach is more suitable and in what scenarios.

Best,
-V

Comment: The second and third approaches are singletons, which easily lead to new global mutable state, which is bad.

Comment: can u please elaborate a bit!

Comment: @vaibhav singletons tend to act as global variables, i.e. introduce global state into your application. Since `Object`s in Javascript are mutable by default, this global state is moreover potentially mutable.

Answer (score 3):

Your first approach exports the class and allows anyone who loads your module to create as many instances of your object as they would like.

Your second approach exports only a single object, no matter how many separate callers all load your module.  This is called a singleton and all customers of this module would share the same single object.

Your third approach is not much different in practical usage from the second approach.  It is also a singleton in that all callers get access to the same object.  Your variable `DB` is not a global.  It's a module-level variable that is only accessible to the code inside this module.  The third approach has the advantage that the `DB` variable cannot be messed with by outside code, whereas in your first approach, that data is stored in the object's instance data and can be accessed by anyone.

The first two options offer very different features (freely create many objects vs. singleton).  YOU have to decide whether you want to export the class so others can create their own instances or whether you want to export only a single object and all callers share the same object.  This is an architectural choice for you to make and we cannot make it for you because it depends only upon what you want to export and what functionality you want the customers of this module to have.  There are reasons to want all users of the module to share the same object and there are reasons for each user to be able to instantiate their own object.  You have to decide which you want.

Comment: @vaibhav - Does this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points.